# In Yii2 how can I use a class in the root folder?

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to use my class `rootfolder/assets/AppAsset.php` from my backend class `rootfolder/backend/views/layouts/view.php` however I can't seem to reference it.

I cannot do `\assets\AppAsset`, `..\..\assets\AppAssets`

Is there a way I can use this class that is inside the root folder from my backend app?

My project stucture is

```
RootFolder/
    backend/
    assets/AppAsset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting this in my PSR-4 in composer.json

```
"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "myAlias\\": "./",
        }
    },
```

Then inside of my root file I can do use myAlias\assets\AppAsset;
and I can do the same in the backend and it gets both fine without having to do any if statements on the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-autoloading) your class definition must be [PSR-4 compliant](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md). Therefore you must define the right namespace in your class definition. For example like this:

```
namespace app\assets;

class AppAssets
{

}
```

Then you could reference the class by using

```
use app\assets\AppAsset

AppAsset::register($this);

...
```

When using the Basic Project Template, you may put your classes under the top-level namespace app so that they can be autoloaded by Yii without the need of defining a new alias. This is because @app is a predefined alias, and a class name like app\components\MyClass can be resolved into the class file AppBasePath/components/MyClass.php, according to the algorithm just described.

In the Advanced Project Template, each tier has its own root alias. For example, the front-end tier has a root alias @frontend, while the back-end tier root alias is @backend. As a result, you may put the front-end classes under the namespace frontend while the back-end classes are under backend. This will allow these classes to be autoloaded by the Yii autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

In my project I'm not using frontend. My project structure looks like this.

https://prnt.sc/4LOB8imWJSLm

I have my models/views/controllers in the base folder in order to have no frontend/web in the slug.

Which means that I cannot use app to go down a level from backend as app will be 'backend' and won't get assets/AppAsset from the root folder